App sometimes crashing when installing signed debuggable version
I have for years now built my app in two different ways: signed debuggable release and signed non-debuggable release. When installing my debugging version, I sometimes get a crash when installing my apk through adb. Sometimes I have to install it multiple times before it works. This does NOT happen with the non-debuggable version. I have noticed this  for the past couple of months while running the latest Android Studio (?Dolphin and now Jellyfish) and a Pixel 6 Pro on Android 14.

Debuggable signed release:
 debuggable true
 minifyEnabled false
 shrinkResources false


Non-debuggable signed release (production):
debuggable false
minifyEnabled true
shirnkResources true



I create the apk by going to Android Studio's "Build -> Generate signed app bundle / apk". I do it this way so I can go back and forth between debuggable and non-debuggable apk on the same device without having to uninstall the app first. Installing a "traditional" debugging apk uses a debug key which doesn't allow that.
I install either of these apks with adb with this command:
./adb install -r -d /Users/Flyview/Android/Android\ Studio/lockmeout/app/release/app-release.apk 

Here's the main error of the logcat:
2024-06-03 13:23:59.798  2638-2638  CarrierSvcBindHelper                 D  onPackageUpdateFinished: com.package.app
2024-06-03 13:23:59.801  2638-2638  CarrierSvcBindHelper                 D  onPackageModified: com.package.app
2024-06-03 13:23:59.803 24064-24073 libc                                 A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x743100ec50 in tid 24073 (ADB-JDWP Connec), pid 24064 (kage.app)

Has anyone seen this before? What can I try to investigate?

I have temporarily solved this by setting "debuggable false" even in my non-shrinked debugging builds. This used to mean that logDebug calls would not get printed to logcat, but it seems to be working even without it. Not sure what's changed with the framework.
